# Decode python tuple

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, psycopg2

I am fetching a number of rows from a PostgreSQL database using Psycopg2. Everything is working fine, except the encoding. The database is encoded in UTF-8.

This returns the result I want:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
row = cur.fetchone().decode('utf-8')
```

But how do I do the same for `cur.fetchall()`? I tried looping over the returned tuple but that didn't work.

**EDIT:**

Here's my decoding function that gives `'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'` in Django.

```
def dec(tup):
  res = []
  for row in tup:
    res.append(row.decode('utf-8'))
  return res
```

Comment: Why are you using raw psycopg2 interface with Django? You should use Django ORM instead, it has support for raw queries (if you need a really complicated query) and will do all decoding for you.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev: Sure, but that's not really what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do any decoding.  Psycopg does that for you.  Remove all that `decode` business.

Comment: ... unless the input to the database is similarly mangled (double-encoded UTF-8, for example). In which case, remove the corresponding `encode` calls that mangle the data in the first place too.